# Which one of the following numbers is prime: $42^7-65^8$ , $27^{40}-28^8$ , $114(2^{127}-1)+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think three strategies may be used here to check for prime numbers:
1) decomposition
2) finding remainder modulo x
3) using a special theorem
But unfortunately I haven't been able to solve the problem...
Please help

Comment: $27^{40}-28^8=(27^{20})^2-(28^4)^2=(27^{20}+28^4)(27^{20}-28^4)$

Comment: You're welcome. Do you consider negative numbers? $42^7-65^8<0$.

Comment: You  are right,and prime numbers are not negative,but this was a guidance school  exam problem and I didn't suppose the problem itself may be erroneous...

Comment: It is not erroneous; on the contrary, then we can easily say that the first number is not prime - because it's not positive.

Comment: I'm not sure what a guidance school exam is or what level of knowledge is expected.  If it's fairly elementary and multiple choice then I expect the intended answer is:  not #1) It's clearly negative not #2) It's a difference of squares yes #3) because not 1 and not 2.  If this is the intended strategy, I don't like it for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last number is indeed a prime (the AKS-test returns "prime"). The middle one is divisible by $5$, hence not prime. Indeed, $27^{40}\equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and $28^8\equiv 1\bmod 5$. The first one is not prime, either.
Here I have the decomposition $42^7-65^8=-361447\cdot 880943191$, but certainly there is a better way.

Comment: All of the above numbers are odd, not even.

Comment: There should be a systematic way to solve this,because the actual numbers become so huge

Comment: How could you decompose the first number?

Comment: Probably for the first one is to make the simple observation that the number is negative.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi : I used a factorization algorithm for integers.

Comment: A theoretical argument would be nice, but I am happy with AKS.

Comment: Guys,Thank you all so much

Comment: The second is a difference of squares. I noted (and thought it odd) that the first one was negative but if that's the intended reason, I'd nitpick that it's not universally accepted that negative numbers can not be prime.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, indeed. One often speaks of "rational" primes, in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is there a proof that the third number is prime?

Comment: In 1876 Lucas proved that $M_{127}=2^{127}-1 $ is prime. Then the people studied the numbers $kM_{127}+1$ for different $k$, e.g., for $k=144, 124, 388, 408, 498, 696, 738, 774, 780, 934$ - see [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/by_year.html).